# Using external mixins in Angular component style

Tags: angular, sass, components, styles, mixins

I have a problem with using SCSS mixin and function (defined in external scss file) in Angular component stylesheet.

I have scss themes.scss file creating in src/styles/themes.scss:

```
$themes: ( dark: ( backgroundColor: $background-color--dark, primaryFontColor: $primary-font-color--dark, blockBgColor: $block-color--dark, sidebarBgColor: $sidebar-background-color--dark, navigationItemBg: $navigation-item-background--dark, navigationItemBgHover: $navigation-item-background-hover--dark, navigationItemBorder: $navigation-item-border--dark, headerBgColor: $header-background-color--dark ), light: ( backgroundColor: $background-color--light, primaryFontColor: $primary-font-color--light, blockBgColor: $block-color--light, sidebarBgColor: $sidebar-background-color--light, navigationItemBg: $navigation-item-background--light, navigationItemBgHover: $navigation-item-background-hover--light, navigationItemBorder: $navigation-item-border--light, headerBgColor: $header-background-color--light ), );

@mixin themed() {
    @each $theme, $map in $themes {
        .theme--#{$theme} &{
            $theme-map: () !global;

            @each $key, $submap in $map {
                $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
                $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
            }

            @content;
            $theme-map: null !global;
        }
    }
}

@function t($k) {
    @return map-get($theme-map, $k);
}
```

In this file I have variables also defined.Then, if I import this file to global style.scss file, everything works fine. But when I'm trying to import this themes.scss file to local component style and using mixin, it doesn't work:

```
@import "../../../styles/themes.scss";

.header {

    @include themed() {
        background-color: t("backgroundColor");
        color: t("primaryFontColor");
    }

[...]
```

Next thing is, that if I want to use in component style one of variables defined in themes.scss - it also works without any problems. So it looks like problem is with using mixin, or with mixin itself.

Could you provide me a way to make this work? Thank you.

Comment: Any errors....?

Comment: Nope. Angular cli doesn't produce any error during compilations. In themes.scss I created simple function that return value, and this function works in component stylesheet. So I think there is a problem with mixin.